# How do I prompt a new Window showing the model data from the selected item?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

My goal here is to show a new Window when right-clicking an item in the `ItemsControl` and selecting `Edit` in the `ContextMenu`

This is what I have so far.
I have my `MainWindow.xaml` which would be the MainView of the application
and on that View I have a `ItemsControl` with the `DataTemplate` of `UserCard` which is a custom `UserControl`.

The `ItemsControl` has a `ItemSource` set to my `ObservableCollection` in my ViewModel

I set the DataContext in the code-behind like so.

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new BaseViewModel();
        }
```

And here is the XAML

```
<StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CardViewModel.Users}"
                          dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
                          dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
                          dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultEffectDataTemplate="True">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <controls:UserCard>
                            <controls:UserCard.ContextMenu>
                                <!-- Bind the DataContext of the CM to the DataContext that's bound to the RootObject-->
                                <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding DataContext, Source={local:RootObject}}">
                                    <MenuItem Header="Edit"
                                              Command="{Binding CardViewModel.EditUser}" 
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </controls:UserCard.ContextMenu>
                        </controls:UserCard>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>
```

Now it does display two `UserCard` controls because in the ViewModel I've added two objects to the collection of which it's `ItemSource` derrives from.

However when I click the `MenuItem` in the `ContextMenu` I want to open a new Window that displays `TextBlock` controls and they should be bound to differet properties from my Model.

I have no idea how to pass that model on to the new Window

Here is the UserControl

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Width="180"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Margin="10"
                   FontFamily="Consolas"/>


    <TextBlock Width="100"
                   Height="20"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Margin="5"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   FontFamily="Consolas" />


    <TextBlock Width="100"
                   Height="20"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Text="{Binding Id}"
                   FontFamily="Consolas"/>
</Grid>
```

The binding there works just fine! I can see the Name and everything in my ItemsControl `MainWindow` but when I right click the `UserControl` and it displays the new Window I don't know how to pass it on.

NewWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
        <TextBlock Height="25" Text="{Binding SelectedItemViewModel.Name}"/>
    </Grid>
```

ViewModel

```
class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public CardViewModel CardViewModel { get; set; } = new CardViewModel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding to `SelectedItemViewModel.Name`, but I don't see this property in the view model...